# DynamoDB conditional updateItem on non-range id

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table that'll be for tracking "hits" associated to browser name on a daily basis.

This is setup like this:

- ID (page_id - hash)
- Browser (S)
- Hits (N)
- Created (N - range)

I'd like to use `updateItem` to atomically update the Hits value.  This would need to take into account the ID, Browser and Created.

As it is, it will overwrite the Browser value for an update on same day for a particular ID. I could put the range on Browser, but then it would be the same concern with Created, where it shouldn't update any previous days.

Any ideas a better way to design this so that I can achieve this?  Thank you

Edit:  Just thinking of another potential option.  Instead of having the ID simply as the page_id, it could be a concatenation of page_id and the browser, so `page_chrome` for instance.  Then I could add an property which would could be a secondary index which holds PageId that could be queried on.  Still not sure if this would be the ideal solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would concatenate the browser to the page_id something like
`page#browser`. And if needed have them as separate attributes for more indexes. Your edit is spot on imo. You can then even have page#all to count all browsers together beforehand.

Just in case you missed it, here's the [doc on atomic counters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I ended up doing and works perfect, page#all is a great idea.